# How to Check if the browser supports HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, swfobject

**EDIT** I have changed some Javascript now, so if I can find a javascript function that detects HTML5 Video support, it *should* work.

I have a HTML5 video player that has flash fallback, if HTML5 isnt supported, I want it to fallback to flash. Im currently using

`<!--[if !IE]><!--> then load my custom player
else use SWFObject to render it.`

Is it possible to do the folllowing:

```
`  If (HTML5 supported browser) {
 <some html and script>  (My custom player)
}else{
  <different html and script> (I would call  SWFobject here)
}
`
```

Trying to find a nice easy solution idea.

Usually I would be able to have an additional `<object>` in the video tag, but this won't be possible due to the way the player is inserted into the page.

Even though I can detect HTML5 support with a possibly unreliable method, I'm not sure how to have my HTML based on the output of the support

Comment: There is not a 1:1 mapping between browsers that support one arbitrary feature introduced in HTML 5 and another arbitrary feature introduced in HTML 5. Testing `navigator.geolocation` to see if the browser will support your video is a terrible idea.

Comment: That's why I don't want to use it/

Comment: i have the same question if any one get the answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you had a look at http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-css

It can do feature detection

Comment: Thanks, I made a JS method to do it, but seems that Modernizr is just..... better

Comment: but how can we use this modernizer can you give some example code

Comment: @404 - See modernizrs HTML feature detection here: http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5.   For example, if you wanted to check if the HTML5 canvas was supported you would do `if(Modernizr.canvas){ ...`  You may also want to look at HTML5 Shiv's for mocking HTML5 in older browsers.

Answer (score 10):

The better solution is to use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to do your feature detection on the client-side.Modernizr is an open source, MIT-licensed JavaScript library that detects support for many HTML5 & CSS3 features.
If your browser does not support the canvas API, the Modernizr.canvas property will be false.

```
if (Modernizr.canvas) {
  // let's draw some shapes!
} else {
  // no native canvas support available :(
}
```

[Ref](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html)

Another solution if you are using JQuery:
Checking for support for the canvas element of HTML 5

```
var test_canvas = document.createElement("canvas") //try and create sample canvas element
var canvascheck=(test_canvas.getContext)? true : false //check if object supports getContext() method, a method of the canvas element
alert(canvascheck) //alerts true if browser supports canvas element
```

[Ref](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck.shtml)

Comment: Or for bonus points, use the YEPNOPE addin within Modernizr, then load up excanvas if it's not supported :)

Answer (score 9):

One liner check...

```
// Plain JavaScript
(typeof document.createElement('canvas').getContext === "function") 

// Or... Using lodash
_.isFunction(document.createElement('canvas').getContext)
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out everything at [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#techniques) especially the 'Detecting HTML5 Techniques' section. It has pretty much everything you may need.

Answer (score -3):

Here is how w3schools does it:

```
function checkVideo()
{
if(!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType)
  {
  var vidTest=document.createElement("video");
  oggTest=vidTest.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"');
  if (!oggTest)
    {
    h264Test=vidTest.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
    if (!h264Test)
      {
      document.getElementById("checkVideoResult").innerHTML="Sorry. No video support."
      }
    else
      {
      if (h264Test=="probably")
        {
        document.getElementById("checkVideoResult").innerHTML="Yeah! Full support!";
        }
      else
        {
        document.getElementById("checkVideoResult").innerHTML="Meh. Some support.";
        }
      }
    }
  else
    {
    if (oggTest=="probably")
      {
      document.getElementById("checkVideoResult").innerHTML="Yeah! Full support!";
      }
    else
      {
      document.getElementById("checkVideoResult").innerHTML="Meh. Some support.";
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("checkVideoResult").innerHTML="Sorry. No video support."
  }
}
```

Comment: W3Schools suck. Just sayin'.