# Check if YouTube Player is using HTML5/Flash

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Is there a way to check, whether the YouTube Player is using Flash/HTML5 using the YouTube Iframe API?

I'm using this code for YouTube embeds

```
<iframe id="widget2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C6Cyrpkb25k/?feature=player_detailpage&enablejsapi=1&origin=https://example.com" height="360" width="640" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486655/detect-if-client-using-html5-youtube-player

Answer (score 0):

YouTube will use HTML5 when it can in this case, and fall back to Flash when HTML5 is not available. While I'm not sure you can specifically check to see what YouTube is doing per se, you can generally check to see what the capabilities of the current browser include. There are *many* different ways to do this. For example, you might consider using the modernizr library (http://modernizr.com/), or reading this question ([How to Check if the browser supports HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498512/how-to-check-if-the-browser-supports-html5))